# NoMethodError and Rollback on Create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating an app where users have tasks, documents, appointments etc, but I keep running into this error when I try to create a new task at /users/:id/tasks/new

NoMethodError in Tasks#create

undefined method `tasks_path' for #<#:0x007ff9ed2fd200>
Did you mean?  asset_path

and in the console logs it says

```
Started POST "/users/2/tasks" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-04-27 22:22:52 -0400
Processing by TasksController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"YG2qRnuHT92OsJ2OkMrU9ztNTD+zVb88jiRN+tr85sX5E68zeGsxkv++ecI76Txx0iNPmX/jw3rLlBRf1EJ0yQ==", "task"=>{"name"=>"d", "description"=>"d"}, "commit"=>"Create Task", "user_id"=>"2"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendering tasks/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered tasks/new.html.erb within layouts/application (161.5ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 170ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `tasks_path' for #<#<Class:0x00555bf7a14598>:0x007ff9ed2fd200>
Did you mean?  asset_path):
    1: New Task:
    2: 
    3: <%= form_for [@user,  @task] do |f| %>
    4: 
    5: <div>
    6: <%= f.label :name %><br/>
```

Here is my controller:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = current_user
    @task = Task.new
  end

  def create
    @user = current_user

    @task = Task.new(task_params)
    if @task.save
      redirect_to '/'
    else
      rendirect_to '/'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
  end

  def show
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @task = Task.all
  end

  private

  def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:name, :description)
  end
end
```

(I was redirecting to '/' for testing purposes)

Here is my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'home#index'
  resources :home, only: [:index]
  resources :users do
    resources :appointments, :tasks, :documents
  end

  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

end
```

task.rb

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password

  has_many :tasks
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :documents
end
```

and finally the view for new tasks

```
<%= form_for [@user,  @task] do |f| %>

<div>
<%= f.label :name %><br/>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div>
<%= f.label :description %><br/>
<%= f.text_area :description %>
</div>

<%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

Been pulling out my hair for hours so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues. The rollback is due to a validation failing. In this case it's implicit: `belongs_to` validates existence by default. Since you don't actually assign the user to the task, it's `nil`. Try this:

```
def create
  @task = Task.new(task_params)
  @task.user = current_user

  # ...
end
```

As for `task_path` not existing, I believe it's because you have it nested. You can always check `rake routes` or hit a non-existent page in your application to get a list of the available route helpers. In this case, I think you should un-nest `tasks` from `users` because you aren't actually using the `user_id` param in the URL.

```
resources :users
resources :tasks
```

Then you're set.

Oh, and watch for typos: you have `rendirect_to` in your `create` action `else` clause. You almost certainly meant `redirect_to`.

Comment: Thanks! So I unnested those classes, for some reason I was under the impression that if you had a has_many / belongs_to relationship you should nest them. Either way, it's now giving me a unknown attribute user_id error but I believe I just have to migrate a user_id attribute to the tasks table. Otherwise, working!

Comment: @Grambam Yep, if you don't already, you'll need a `user_id` column on the `tasks` table for that `belongs_to` relationship to work.